# Accidently running perl-script with sh, how to detect that and take actions?

Tags: linux, bash, perl

I had a bash-backup-script for quite some time which worked ok for me, but now I needed some features and put them into a perl-script. It works perfectly fine, and I'm happy. But my muscle-memory always wants to type "sh backup" instead of "perl backup" (or using "./backup" or something like that). I happened to start with "sh backup" and now I can barely get rid of that anymore.

My idea was this:

Having a module cleverfilter.pm:

```
package cleverfilter;
use Filter::Simple;
FILTER {
    s/perl backup; exit;//g;
};
1;
```

and this in my backup-script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use cleverfilter;

perl backup; exit;

use strict;
use warnings;
...
```

The idea behind that was that a perl-script would (through the filter) remove the "perl backup; exit;"-part, but bash wouldn't. Perl would run fine, and bash would run this script as a perl-script.

But Filter::Simple seems to have one problem: it filters everything *after* it's modules use. That's why I needed to put it on top of the "perl backup"-line. Now, when I run it with perl, it works like a charm. Running it with bash, obviously, gives me these problems:

```
backup: 3: backup: use: not found
```

Of course, I could just create an empty program "use" somewhere that ignores all the parameters coming, but that's not a nice solution to this.

So, my question here: is there any way to write some script-part that will be executed with bash, but not with perl? Some kind of comment, e.g., like in HTML with those weird IE-Style-Comment-Tags?

Or is there any better solution? Something easier I haven't thought of yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to use the `perl -x` option like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
perl -x "$0"
exit
#!/bin/perl
#perl code goes here
```

On my system that works for either sh or perl.